# Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, integration-testing, moq

First of all, I googled all SO posts on this but none helped me. I get the exception on the subject on below piece.

```
 [Test]
    public void TestInv()
    {
        string inReference = "123";
        _Service.Setup(q=> q.InvoiceS(inReference ));
        _Service.Verify(q => q.InvoiceS(inReference ), Times.AtLeastOnce());
    }
```

Comment: What is the SUT? please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your example you are not calling InvoiceS. In unit testing you have a term called AAA which stands for Arrange, Act and Assert. Essentially you are not doing the Act of your Unit Test.